# Generate only setter method for field in Eclipse (or SpringSource Tool Suite)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Can I generate in Eclipse only setter(s) (without getter(s)) of field(s)?
In Spring I don't need getters in many beans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. Go to "Generate Getters and Setters" and click on "Select Setters".

Comment: ok thanks, indeed in Source menu there it is (in shortcut link at left margin of editor is only getter+setter at once)